# How to snap a draggable upon creation in plain javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop

I need to create draggable elements already snapped to a target, I couldn't find any example about it in the documentation, google or here...

I know there's a snapElements array on the widget which contains the available snap targets, and I think the solution may be somewhere over there, but I don't know how to set the draggable to the target programmatically.

Should I trigger some event?

Comment: What are you talking about? What widget?

Comment: @empiric this one: http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/

Comment: We need to see some example code. I suspect what you're referring to is the widgets ability to get the position of the target element, and set that, via CSS, of the draggable, such that when dropped it snaps into place.

Comment: @Twisty let me get back to you tomorrow at work

Comment: @Typo Any luck?

Comment: @Twisty nope, just went another way...sorry to let you hanging there. It's weird that a functionality like that it wasn't contemplated though.